# How does the logic OR operator work inside of a while loop in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, logical-operators

I have a while loop using a logical OR operator, but I can only ever get one of the conditions to close the loop.

`while (hourTime <= 23 || input != 4)`

What I mean by that is the condition checking the 'hourTime' variable works by itself and so does the condition checking the 'input'.  But when I combine them using the OR operator only the 'input' check works.  I've tried enclosing each one within their own parenthesis, but that didn't seem to fix the issue either.  Any help would be appreciated. I can post more code if needed.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS //added this because I kept getting a warning about using localtime
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


time_t now = time(0); //gets current Time
tm* ltm = localtime(&now); //converts current Time to struct tm type

int hourTime = ltm->tm_hour;
int minuteTime = ltm->tm_min;
int secondTime = ltm->tm_sec;


int input;



//adds another minute or hour when seconds or minutes reach 60
void AddTime() {

    if (secondTime >= 60) {
        minuteTime = minuteTime + 1;
        secondTime = 0;
    }

    if (minuteTime >= 60) {
        hourTime = hourTime + 1;
        minuteTime = 0;
    }
    secondTime = secondTime + 1;

}

//waits a second then clears screen
void WaitAndClear() {

    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "\033[2J\033[1;1H";

}

//checks user input and handles it accordingly
void CheckUserInput(int userInput) {

    switch (userInput) {
        case 1:
            hourTime = hourTime + 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            minuteTime = minuteTime + 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            secondTime = secondTime + 1;
            break;
        case 4:
            input = 4;
            cout << "You have exited" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;
            break;

    }


}

//displays clock in standard format
void StandardClockTime(int hour, int minute, int second) {

    string amOrPm = "A M";

    if (hour >= 12) {
        amOrPm = "P M";
    }

    if (hour > 12) {
        hour = hour - 12;
    }
    
    cout << "****************************" << endl;
    cout << "*       12-HourClock       *" << endl;
    cout << "*       " << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hour << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << minute << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << second << " " << amOrPm << "       *" << endl;
    cout << "****************************" << endl;

}

//displays time in military time
void MilitaryTime(int hour, int minute, int second) {

    cout << "****************************" << endl;
    cout << "*       24-HourClock       *" << endl;
    cout << "*         " << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hour << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << minute << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << second << "         *" << endl;
    cout << "****************************" << endl;
}

//displays menu for user
void DisplayMenu() {

    cout << "****************************" << endl;
    cout << "* 1 - Add One Hour         *" << endl;
    cout << "* 2 - Add One Minute       *" << endl;
    cout << "* 3 - Add One Second       *" << endl;
    cout << "* 4 - Exit Program         *" << endl;
    cout << "****************************" << endl;

}



int main() {

    //these variables are for testing purposes
    hourTime = 22;
    minuteTime = 59;
    secondTime = 50;

    while (hourTime <= 23 || input != 4) {



        WaitAndClear();
        AddTime();
        StandardClockTime(hourTime, minuteTime, secondTime);
        MilitaryTime(hourTime, minuteTime, secondTime); 
        DisplayMenu();
        cin >> input;
        CheckUserInput(input);

        
    }




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what OR means. It should check if either of them is true and if one is true it doesn't even bother to check the other. I guess what you want here is the AND operator instead?

Comment: Please show the actual values when the condition does not work as expected.

Comment: I understand how the OR operator works, but what I'm saying is one of the conditions completely stops working once they are placed together and it's usually the hourTime.

Comment: @SpaceyBot this is applicable only to the standard operator|| until C++17. Once you overload it, they loose their special sequencing properties.

Comment: oh sorry then i didn't know. thanks @S.M

Comment: **one of the conditions completely stops working once they are placed together** what does it mean? Could you reword this with the example values?

Comment: @SpaceyBot It's ok. OP edited the question, no overloaded || is used there.

Comment: @S.M. posted the entirety of my code because it would have been a little difficult to get the point across with just snippets.

Comment: The code is not enough. What is your input? Are you sure you should run the loop before `input` has been input? It is 0 in the first iteration. Perhaps you should `DisplayMenu(); cin >> input; CheckUserInput(input);` before the loop? Or replace the while loop with a do-while loop?

Comment: @S.M Code isn't enough? That is the entirety of the code that I'm working on. And as for the input, the clocks and menu are to be displayed first, asking for input pauses the whole loop, unless there is a way around pausing the loop to ask for input.

Comment: The code is not enough since we don't know your input and expectations. Just try to describe with which conditions the program should continue run and with which conditions the program should exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator is working just fine.  The loop continues if either condition is met.  It exits if both conditions are violated.  (That's just paraphrasing [DeMorgan's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)).

If you want it to exit if any one condition is violated, then you should be using the "logical AND" (`&&`) operator.

Comment: Then.. I guess I don't understand the OR operator.  I thought it was supposed to work when one of the operands are true.  EDIT:  I think I get it now. So, because the while loop needs both operands to be true to work, the second one of them is false it stops executing.

Comment: @Bmore - It is.   Your problem is not understanding how that interacts with a loop construct.   The condition in the loop specifies when the loop continues, not when it terminates.   Your description says you want the loop to terminate if either of the conditions are true, but your code (the direction to the compiler) specifies that the loop should *continue* if either of the conditions are true.

Answer (score 0):

The logical **OR** operator is only evaluated as true when one of its operands evaluates true.
If you want to check both conditions simultaneously, then use the logical **AND** operator i.e `&&`. It's got only evaluated if both conditions are true. Your code will look like this.

```
while (hourTime <= 23 && input != 4){
\\Your statement
}
```

Comment: speaking of using nested loops @KushagraSingh, is it possible to have one loop constantly run the clock and have a separate loop just checking user input.  That way the clock can work in real time without being paused by the user input?

Comment: The nested while loop is definitely NOT the same.  If the outer one is true it will check the inner condition (like a single loop using `&&`).  If the inner one is true it will loop.  But unlike the single loop with `&&`, the outer condition becoming false will not stop the inner loop (it will keep doing processing), and the inner condition becoming false will not stop the outer loop (it will hang)

Comment: Thanks, @BenVoigt for correcting my mistake.

Comment: Yes @Bmore, but you have to use two separate loops. The first loop will run the clock and another loop will check the user input.